# Twitter OAuth with WinJS

Tags: twitter-oauth, winjs

Trying to authenticate with Twitter since over a week trough my Windows 8 app, but no success.

My app is registered at Twitter and it should be able to read, write and sign in.

I think I've tried all the descriptions at Twitter documentation, but nothing works. Guess the problem is at me, but can't find it.

I get always the 403 forbidden response.

My code:

```
function getTwitterCredentials() {

    WinJS.xhr({
        type:"get",
        url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate",
        headers: {
            consumerKey: "ZSNRXXXXXXXXX",
            userKey: "GVknHzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            Authorization: "OAuth",
            oauth_consumer_key: "ZSNRtXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            oauth_nonce: "b7efbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
            oauth_signature: "23zb0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_timestamp: "1368555677",
            oauth_token: "1408XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
            oauth_version: "1.0"
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
       //it it works here some will be some action 
    }, function error(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
    });
}
```

Someone has experience whit this issue?

Thanks Marlowe

Comment: have you tried [web authentication sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122) - it has scenario for twitter sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some demo JS code I slightly modified from an existing sample on our site from the oAuth Web Authentication Broker for Win8 demo. Search 'oob' for my changes, they are minor.

In addition, the Linq to Twitter project is pretty awesome so may want to consider checking that out as well and would prob be a bit easier. It handles the auth fairly automatically and doesn't require having to enter in the token response.

```
//// THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
//// ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
//// THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
//// PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
////
//// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/oAuthTwitter.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            document.getElementById("oAuthTwitterLaunch").addEventListener("click", launchTwitterWebAuth, false);
            //did read that this is required for oAuth in a win8 app, however twitter uses 'oob' for a desktop app's callback url.
            //in fact your app will show it.
            //var endURI = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.getCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
            //document.getElementById("TwitterCallbackURL").innerText = endURI.displayUri;
        }
    });

    function sendRequest(url) {
        try {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", url, false);
            request.send(null);
            return request.responseText;
        } catch (err) {
            WinJS.log("Error sending request: " + err, "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");
        }
    }

    function sendPostRequest(url, authzheader) {
        try {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", url, false);
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authzheader);
            request.send(null);
            if (request.status != "200") {
                console.log(request);
            }
            return request.responseText;
        } catch (err) {
            WinJS.log("Error sending request: " + err, "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");            
        }
    }

    function isValidUriString(uriString) {
        var uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriString);
        }
        catch (err) {
        }
        return uri !== null;
    }

    var authzInProgress = false;

    function launchTwitterWebAuth() {
        var twitterURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

        // Get all the parameters from the user
        var clientID = document.getElementById("TwitterClientID").value;
        if (clientID === null || clientID === "") {
            WinJS.log("Please enter a ClientID for Twitter App", "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");            
            return;
        }

        var clientSecret = document.getElementById("TwitterSecret").value;
        if (clientSecret === null || clientSecret === "") {
            WinJS.log("Please enter a Secret for Twitter App", "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");            
            return;
        }

        var callbackURL = document.getElementById("TwitterCallbackURL").value;
        //if (!isValidUriString(callbackURL)) {
        //    WinJS.log("Please enter a Callback URL for Twitter", "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");            
        //    return;
        //}

        if (authzInProgress) {
            document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "\r\nAuthorization already in Progress ...";
            return;
        }

        // Acquiring a request token
        var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
        var nonce = Math.random();
        nonce = Math.floor(nonce * 1000000000);

        // Compute base signature string and sign it.
        //    This is a common operation that is required for all requests even after the token is obtained.
        //    Parameters need to be sorted in alphabetical order
        //    Keys and values should be URL Encoded.
        var sigBaseStringParams = "oauth_callback=" + encodeURIComponent(callbackURL);
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + clientID;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp;
        sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
        var sigBaseString = "POST&";
        sigBaseString += encodeURIComponent(twitterURL) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(sigBaseStringParams);

        var keyText = clientSecret + "&";
        var keyMaterial = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(keyText, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var macAlgorithmProvider = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.MacAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
        var key = macAlgorithmProvider.createKey(keyMaterial);
        var tbs = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(sigBaseString, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var signatureBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.sign(key, tbs);
        var signature = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(signatureBuffer);
        var dataToPost = "OAuth oauth_callback=\"" + encodeURIComponent(callbackURL) + "\", oauth_consumer_key=\"" + clientID + "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature=\"" + encodeURIComponent(signature) + "\"";
        var response = sendPostRequest(twitterURL, dataToPost);
        var oauth_token;
        var oauth_token_secret;
        var keyValPairs = response.split("&");

        for (var i = 0; i < keyValPairs.length; i++) {
            var splits = keyValPairs[i].split("=");
            switch (splits[0]) {
                case "oauth_token":
                    oauth_token = splits[1];
                    break;
                case "oauth_token_secret":
                    oauth_token_secret = splits[1];
                    break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "\r\nOAuth Token = " + oauth_token;
        document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "\r\nOAuth Token Secret = " + oauth_token_secret;

        // Send the user to authorization
        twitterURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + oauth_token;

        document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "\r\nNavigating to: " + twitterURL + "\r\n";
        var startURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(twitterURL);
        //var endURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(callbackURL);
        //we use 'oob' in the request_auth, but now for authorize, we use the apps URI.
        var endURI = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.getCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
        authzInProgress = true;
        Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(
            Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationOptions.none, startURI, endURI)
            .done(function (result) {
                document.getElementById("TwitterReturnedToken").value = result.responseData;
                document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "Status returned by WebAuth broker: " + result.responseStatus + "\r\n";
                if (result.responseStatus === Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus.errorHttp) {
                    document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += "Error returned: " + result.responseErrorDetail + "\r\n";
                }
                authzInProgress = false;
            }, function (err) {
                WinJS.log("Error returned by WebAuth broker: " + err, "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");
                document.getElementById("TwitterDebugArea").value += " Error Message: " + err.message + "\r\n";
                authzInProgress = false;
            });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi Adam, this looks like great stuff. 
But I'm a bit confused. I get a consumer_key, but what is the customer secret and what is the callback url in a win 8 app?

Comment: The key to successfully authentication in Win 8 apps seems to set the callback url to "oob". Then it's possible to send the users authorization request.

Comment: For those coming to this, I use nothing but this library now: https://github.com/cauld/winjs-oauth-for-twitter

Comment: Forked that and turned into a Universal app https://github.com/sebagomez/winjs-oauth-for-twitter