# Winjs and Onedrive integration

Tags: winjs, onedrive

How can I integrate Onedrive with Winjs. A search showed no result, but I found the dvlup challenge, for onedirve integration (not sepcific to Winjs).

Comment: [javascript api link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631839.aspx) on this page might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by WinJS. If only a web app, then use OneDrive exposed API straight away just like any Javascript API. OneDrive uses OAuth for logging in: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm

In WinJS case this means utilizing XHR and Promises. You can find some tips for OneDrive OAuth from Twitter OAuth from this post: [Twitter OAuth with WinJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902427/twitter-oauth-with-winjs) (They work in same way).

If for specific device, set right manifest rules and possibly need to download SDK for handling files. WinJS includes FileOpenPicker and FileSavePicker for files handling (Found from Windows.Storage.Pickers namespace): https://dev.onedrive.com/sdks.htm

Comment: thanks for answering the question half a year later, I can't really check it it works but I will accept it ;)